# How to receive 1 row from a mysql join instead of 4

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT
    pe.entity_id,
    pev.attribute_id,
    pev.entity_id,
    if(pev.attribute_id='134', pev.value, null) as garantie,
    if(pev.attribute_id='97', pev.value, null) as url,
    if(pev.attribute_id='71', pev.value, null) as nume,
    if(pev.attribute_id='85', pev.value, null) as poza
    FROM
    mg_catalog_product_entity pe,
    mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar pev
    WHERE
    pev.entity_id=pe.entity_id and
    (pev.attribute_id='134' or pev.attribute_id='97'  or pev.attribute_id='71'  or pev.attribute_id='85')
```

i have this mysql join that returns 4 rows like this:

```
value1 null null null 
null value2 null null 
null null value3 null 
null null null value4
```

what i must do in order to receive only one row like this?

```
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

Comment: Don't store data like that, with attribute_id's. Use proper columns (or even tables) for different type of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    pe.entity_id,
    max(if(pev.attribute_id='134', pev.value, null)) as garantie,
    max(if(pev.attribute_id='97', pev.value, null)) as url,
    max(if(pev.attribute_id='71', pev.value, null)) as nume,
    max(if(pev.attribute_id='85', pev.value, null)) as poza
FROM
    mg_catalog_product_entity pe
JOIN
    mg_catalog_product_entity_varchar pev
ON 
    pev.entity_id = pe.entity_id
WHERE 
    pev.attribute_id in (134,97,71,85)
GROUP BY 
    pe.entity_id
```

Comment: returns the same thing. i've compared in phpmyadmin both codes and i get same results

Comment: It looks as though you should remove the `attribute_id` from the `GROUP BY` clause. One of the `entity_id`s is also redundant there.

Comment: i've removed pev.attribute_id and pev.entity_id and it's fine. Thanks :)